# Dynamically and Statically importing unmanaged C++ DLLs into C# does not work

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm trying to import some functions from 32 bit and 64 bit DLLs written in unmanaged C++ into my C# project. As a sample, I did this:

**C++ DLL function**

```
long mult(int a, int b) {
    return ((long) a)*((long) b);
}
```

**C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class DynamicDLLImport
    {
        private IntPtr ptrToDll;
        private IntPtr ptrToFunctionToCall;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate int Multiply(int a, int b);
        private Multiply multiply;

        public DynamicDLLImport(string dllName)
        {
            ptrToDll = LoadLibrary(dllName);
            // TODO: Error handling.

            ptrToFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(ptrToDll, "mult");
            // TODO: Error handling.

            // HERE ARGUMENTNULLEXCEPTION
            multiply = (Multiply)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptrToFunctionToCall, typeof(Multiply));
        }

        public int mult_func(int a, int b)
        {
            return multiply(a, b);
        }

        ~DynamicDLLImport()
        {
            FreeLibrary(ptrToDll);
        }
    }

    class DLLWrapper
    {
        private const string Sixtyfour = "c:\\Users\\Hattenn\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\easyDLL0_64.dll";
        private const string Thirtytwo = "c:\\Users\\Hattenn\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication2\\ConsoleApplication2\\easyDLL0.dll";
//        [DllImport(Sixtyfour)]
//        public static extern int mult(int a, int b);
        [DllImport(Thirtytwo)]
        public static extern int mult(int a, int b);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 5;
            int b = 4;
            DynamicDLLImport dllimp = new DynamicDLLImport("easyDLL0.dll");

            Console.WriteLine(DLLWrapper.mult(a, b));
            //Console.WriteLine(dllimp.mult_func(a, b));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Here are the error messages that I get:

1. When I use the DLLWrapper class with the 32 bit DLL file I get "DLLNotFoundException", but the DLL file is exactly in that path.
2. When I use the DLLWrapper class with the 64 bit DLL file and change the "Platform Target" property to "x64" I get the same "DLLNotFoundException", if I try to build with "x86" then I get "BadImageException".
3. When I use the DynamicDLLImport class, I always get "ArgumentNullException" at the line commented with "HERE ARGUMENTNULLEXCEPTION" in the code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the dll was deployed in debug mode and not in a correct way. When it was deployed in release mode, everything seemed to work fine. Anyone having a similar problem should know that compiling the dll in debug mode and just copying it to another computer is not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

How did you export your function from the DLL? Windows DLL's do not automatically export all functions, and C++ will decorate the names such as to tell apart function overloads for example unless you tell it not to, but exactly how is compiler specific, and other languages definitely don't understand it.

You can check by starting the visual studio command prompt, and using the command

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS "your library.dll"
```

Comment: hmm, looks fine, and your ptrToDll is not null? GetProcAddress should defiantly return a valid pointer if ptrToDll and the function names match. DllImport I believe might do some extra stuff to change it, e.g. with stdcall you would might export that function as _mult@8 and the Windows API has its A and W thing for ASCII/Unicode. Speaking of which, make sure the C++ and C# calling conventions match or you might corrupt your stack later (most x86 C defaults to cdecl, and .NET I think defaults to stdcall).

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs to be able to located the DLL at runtime, not just compile time. Put the DLL in your binary folder, or somewhere on the `PATH` and the static import will work.

Comment: Did you declare `mult` as a dll-export method?

Comment: I did get the DLL from my colleague but he knew what he was doing so I don't expect that it's not declared as a dll-export method.

Comment: Look at the DLL sourcecode, it should have a _declspec(dllexport) at the top of the function.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be the problem but I'll ask him, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# method declaration does not match the C++ one:

```
long mult(int a, int b) 

private delegate int Multiply(int a, int b);
```

Try changing the return type to long?

Comment: VC++ long is 32bit, C# long is 64bit. Also unless using some name decorating scheme or such there is no way to validate DLL's in such a way, it would crash at runtime.